# Create REST controller & classes from proto files

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, grpc, proto

With [gRPC on .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) I can define the interface of my service using proto-files.

I need to expose my service as **REST**, too, and would like to define the service once, using `proto`, instead of manually creating it all again.

Is it possible to create **REST** endpoints (`controller` and `request/response-classes`) using `gRPC` on .NET Framework from the `proto` files?

[Update]
For the **REST** endpoints I want to use **JSON** - I just want to create the `controller` and `request/response-classes` from the `proto` files.

For `request/response` it might be possible to use the classes generated for the gRPC-client, but it would be great if I could create a **REST**-controller from the `proto`-file, too.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes

Longer answer: yes but you'd have to write some custom code to read the proto files and then create the controllers in memory on startup. There's not much you can do out the box

A quick search on Google offers [more insight](https://christianfindlay.com/2020/01/10/protobuf-web-api-in-c/)

Comment: Ah, sorry - I actually want to use JSON for the REST API, I just want to generate the request/response-classes from the proto-files.

Comment: For request/response I might even be able to use the generated classes with a json serializer - my main question would be if it is possible to create a (rest)controller from the proto file.